# Problems designing a notch filter based on allpass in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filter-design

I have to design a notch filter based on an allpass but when I plot the resulting filter in MATLAB it does not fit my specification. I'll provide you with some background.

The filter has the following equation:

$$H(z) = \frac{(1+k_2)}{2}\frac{1+2k_1z^{-1}+z^{-2}}{1+k_1(1+k_2)z^{-1}+k_2z^{-2}}$$

where

$$k_1 = -\cos\omega_0, \hspace{1cm} k_2=\frac{1-\tan(\Delta\omega_0/2)}{1+\tan(\Delta\omega_0/2)}$$

The frequency I want the notch to eliminate is **fr = 490.89Hz**, so I compute all the coefficients in MATLAB and then design the function as follows:

```
fr = 490.89;
wr = 2*pi*fr
delta_wr = 2*pi*50
k1 = -cos(wr)
k2 = (1-tan(delta_wr/2))/(1+tan(delta_wr/2))

%TF H(z)
c = (1+k2)/2, num = [1 2*k1 1], den = [1 k1*(1+k2) k2]

freqz(c*num, den, 2e6, Fs)
```

but when analyzing the final filter with freqz(), the result is

[image]

which is obviously not behaving as a notch, and even the frequency is not the desired.

Any answer is welcomed! Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you review the definition of the frequency variables in your equations for k1 and k2. I'd be surprised if those frequency variables are measured in Hz.

Comment: Where do you define your sample rate ?

Comment: I have converted your equations to [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), please check that I have done so correctly and consider using MathJax in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to normalize your design frequencies with `Fs`:

```
wr = 2*pi*fr/Fs
delta_wr = 2*pi*50/Fs
```

If I make those two changes (and assume `Fs = 44100`) then I get the following plot, which is more like what I would expect.

[image: Notch filter after normalizing to sampling rate]

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @MiqueasEzequiel You're welcome!